# How can I achieve cascading dropdown from a single table

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a table. Table consist of 3 columns. id,asset capacity
I have a dropdown1 of asset. I need a dropdown2 for capacity too.
When I select an asset from dropdown1, the corresponding capacity should come in the dropdown2
For example,If asset1 has capacity 10,
the drop down2 should show 1 to 10(as numbers),
for example asset2 has capacity 12,
the drop downlist should show 1 to 12(as numbers)
My second drop down is not getting populated
Please help

```html
 public JsonResult GetMembers(string asset)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            List<Addasset> StateList = db.addasset.Where(x => x.capacity == asset).ToList();
            return Json(StateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

```js
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#asset").change(function() {
                $.get("/Asset/GetMembers",
                    { asset: $("#asset").value()} ,
                    function(data) {
                        $("#capacity").empty();
                        $.each(data,
                            function(index, row) {
                                $("#capacity").append("<option value='" + row.capacity+ "'>" + row.id + "</option>")
                            });
                    });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

```html
 Dropdown for asset and drop down for capacity
 
 <td>
                        @if (ViewBag.list != null)
                        {
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.asset, ViewBag.list as SelectList, "--select asset--", new { @class = "form-control" })

                        }
                        
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.capacity, new SelectList(""), "select members", new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
```

Comment: Shouldn't Where(x => x.capacity == asset) be Where(x => x.asset == asset)

Comment: @NawedKhan I tried but notworking. When I put a breakpoint at getmembers,it is not hitting

Comment: Are you sure the ID of dropdown is asset? is the asset change firing? just do console.log to verify.Thirdly the .get() has a fail handler (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to show the/any errors.

Comment: Tried!. Now its started working